# At terminal print swiftlint information

Tags: swift, swiftlint

After I installed swiftlint, I used the terminal to print the swiftlint information. When I printed the version number, it was correct. However, when I printed the rules, this problem occurred.

[image: pic]

mac: MacBook Pro(M1 chip)
swift: 5.x
Xcode:13.2

Comment: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/3483 ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is connected with your version of swiftlint. It's `0.17.0` and the current version is `0.46.3`.

Try to update it to a newer version?.

Answer (score -1):

Open Xcode -> Open Preferences -> Check if the `Command Line Tools` is selected.

[image]